# Magento restrict user registration to specific email domains

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.7

Need help in restricting user registration to specific email domains (eg @abc.com) in Magento 1.7.

I tried to edit the core files which is not at all recommended procedure. Is there any extension or procedure to achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial may fit your needs: http://www.pixelpaul.net/magento-restrict-user-registration-by-email-domain/

Notice that it also modifies core files. You should move these files into a local. Here is a quick tutorial on [Overriding Magento blocks, models, helpers and controllers](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/)